# How to find value of $x$ in this formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have this formula:

$$1-\frac 1x=y$$

How do I invert this so that, if I have value of $y$, I want to find value of $x$.

I know, but I am pretty dense in math :(

I dont even know what category to put this under! Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Isolate $1/x$ to one side, then reciprocate both sides.

Comment: $x=1/(1-y)$ right?

Comment: @GregoryGrant: Thank you so much!

Comment: another approach may be to multiply both side by $x$, yielding $$x-1=xy$$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align}
1 - \frac{1}{x} &= y \\
1 &= \frac{1}{x} + y \\
1 - y &= \frac{1}{x} \\
x &= \frac{1}{1-y}
\end{align}

If $y = 1$, the above solution is undefined because there is no $x$ such that $1 - \frac{1}{x} = y$ because we would have
\begin{align}
1 - \frac{1}{x} &= 1 \\
\frac{1}{x} &= 0 \\
\end{align}

which is undefined (looking at a [graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28x%29+%3D+1%2Fx) of $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ is another way to see this).

Comment: Thank you Michael, that is so detailed and helped me understand this well

Comment: Done, and thanks once more :)

Answer (score 1):

First write as $1-y=\frac1x$.  Then reciprocate $\frac{1}{1-y}=x$